# Restrict theme option wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes

How I can restrict theme option for all except me (username: john)? How I can do this? I am using charity hub wordpress theme and want to hide charity hub theme option for all except me.

Comment: This can depend on the theme. What theme are you using? Have you tried to change the user permissions? http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: I am using charity Hub theme by goodlayers and purchased from themeforest